# Not able to retrieve normalized CPU utilization percentage using elasticsearch and metricbeat

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, metricbeat

I am trying to retrieve normalized percentage of CPU utilization by using below query.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST  http://localhost:12001/metricbeat*/_search?pretty=true -d '{"query":{"bool":{"must": [{"range": {"system.cpu.total.norm.pct": {"gte": 0.1}}},{"range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "now-10m","lte": "now/m"}}}]}}}'
```

I want normalized percentage for last 10 mins, but i am not getting any data. Below is the response.

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 8,
    "successful" : 8,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

However if i query elasticsearch with "**system.cpu.total.pct**" i get data. Also,  i updated configuration for "CPU" with "**cpu.metrics:  ["percentages", "normalized_percentages", "ticks"]**".

Can anyone let me know why normalized query is not working?

Below is my metricbeat.reference.yml configuration.

```
module: system
  metricsets:
    - cpu             # CPU usage
    - load            # CPU load averages
    - memory          # Memory usage
    - network         # Network IO
    - process         # Per process metrics
    - process_summary # Process summary
    - uptime          # System Uptime
    - core           # Per CPU core usage
    #- diskio         # Disk IO
    - filesystem     # File system usage for each mountpoint
    #- fsstat         # File system summary metrics
    #- raid           # Raid
    #- socket         # Sockets and connection info (linux only)
  enabled: true
  period: 10s
  processes: ['.*']

  # Configure the metric types that are included by these metricsets.
  cpu.metrics:  ["percentages", "normalized_percentages", "ticks"]  # The other available options are normalized_percentages and ticks.
  core.metrics: ["percentages"]  # The other available option is ticks.
```

Elasticsearch module:

```
module: elasticsearch
  metricsets:
    - node
    - node_stats
    #- index
    #- index_recovery
    #- index_summary
    #- shard
    #- ml_job
  period: 10s
  hosts: ["localhost:8881"]
```

I have enable kibana as output host:

```
# Starting with Beats version 6.0.0, the dashboards are loaded via the Kibana API.
# This requires a Kibana endpoint configuration.
setup.kibana:

  # Kibana Host
  # Scheme and port can be left out and will be set to the default (http and 5601)
  # In case you specify and additional path, the scheme is required: http://localhost:5601/path
  # IPv6 addresses should always be defined as: https://[2001:db8::1]:5601
  host: "localhost:8882"
```

Answer (score 2):

What version of metricsbeat you are using ? system.cpu.total.norm.pct is relatively new field and not present on older metricsbeat versions. 
This could be field system.cpu.total.norm.pct itself not part of metricsbeat or condition where system.cpu.total.norm.pct is greater than 0.1 doesnot full fill.

If you want to only retrive one field then it should be part of include section under _source rather then condition itself like below

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST  http://localhost:12001/metricbeat*/_search?pretty=true -d '{ "_source": {"includes": [ "system.cpu.total.norm.pct"]},"query":{"bool":{"must": [{"range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "now-10m","lte": "now/m"}}}]}}}'
```

---

### Explanation for metricsbeat modules configuration

Since there was changes in metricbeat.reference.yml  let me explain flow of how metricsbeat reads the configs for input modules.

Metricsbeat by default reads the metricbeat.yml.

On this file first section is metricbeat.config.modules which defines all the input modules it should be using

```
metricbeat.config.modules:
  # Glob pattern for configuration loading
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
```

so it include all files present under modules.d directory and has suffix yml.

By default only system.yml is active and for other files extension is disabled so they are not part of active modules

```
modules.d/aerospike.yml.disabled
modules.d/apache.yml.disabled
modules.d/ceph.yml.disabled
modules.d/couchbase.yml.disabled
modules.d/docker.yml.disabled
modules.d/dropwizard.yml.disabled
modules.d/elasticsearch.yml.disabled
modules.d/envoyproxy.yml.disabled
modules.d/etcd.yml.disabled
modules.d/golang.yml.disabled
modules.d/graphite.yml.disabled
modules.d/haproxy.yml.disabled
modules.d/http.yml.disabled
modules.d/jolokia.yml.disabled
modules.d/kafka.yml.disabled
modules.d/kibana.yml.disabled
modules.d/kubernetes.yml.disabled
modules.d/kvm.yml.disabled
modules.d/logstash.yml.disabled
modules.d/memcached.yml.disabled
modules.d/mongodb.yml.disabled
modules.d/munin.yml.disabled
modules.d/mysql.yml.disabled
modules.d/nginx.yml.disabled
modules.d/php_fpm.yml.disabled
modules.d/postgresql.yml.disabled
modules.d/prometheus.yml.disabled
modules.d/rabbitmq.yml.disabled
modules.d/redis.yml.disabled
modules.d/system.yml
modules.d/traefik.yml.disabled
modules.d/uwsgi.yml.disabled
modules.d/vsphere.yml.disabled
modules.d/windows.yml.disabled
modules.d/zookeeper.yml.disabled
```

As you see only system.yml don't have extension .disabled and fulfill the condition of include module `path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml` so its included.

You can list down all enabled and disabled module by running below commnad

```
$ ./metricbeat modules list
Enabled:
system

Disabled:
aerospike
apache
ceph
couchbase
docker
dropwizard
elasticsearch
envoyproxy
etcd
golang
graphite
haproxy
http
jolokia
kafka
kibana
kubernetes
kvm
logstash
memcached
mongodb
munin
mysql
nginx
php_fpm
postgresql
prometheus
rabbitmq
redis
traefik
uwsgi
vsphere
windows
zookeeper
```

and change active to disable and disable by running command such as below

```
$ ./metricbeat modules
Manage configured modules

Usage:
  metricbeat modules [command]

Available Commands:
  disable     Disable one or more given modules
  enable      Enable one or more given modules
  list        List modules

Flags:
  -h, --help   help for modules

Global Flags:
  -E, --E setting=value      Configuration overwrite
  -c, --c string             Configuration file, relative to path.config (default "metricbeat.yml")
  -d, --d string             Enable certain debug selectors
  -e, --e                    Log to stderr and disable syslog/file output
      --path.config string   Configuration path
      --path.data string     Data path
      --path.home string     Home path
      --path.logs string     Logs path
      --plugin pluginList    Load additional plugins
      --strict.perms         Strict permission checking on config files (default true)
  -v, --v                    Log at INFO level
```

So if you want to enable kafka module this can be done as below

```
$ ./metricbeat modules enable kafka
Enabled kafka
```

and then check if its active

```
$ ./metricbeat modules list
Enabled:
kafka
system

Disabled:
aerospike
apache
ceph
couchbase
docker
dropwizard
elasticsearch
envoyproxy
etcd
golang
graphite
haproxy
http
jolokia
kibana
kubernetes
kvm
logstash
memcached
mongodb
munin
mysql
nginx
php_fpm
postgresql
prometheus
rabbitmq
redis
traefik
uwsgi
vsphere
windows
zookeeper
```

Once you run the above command it will rename the file `modules.d/kafka.yml.disabled` to `modules.d/kafka.yml` and you can update the modify the configurations present under `modules.d/kafka.yml`

I hope this explanation help to change metricsbeat configurations.

Comment: I am using version 6.6 across ELK stack. Also tried your suggestion and below is as snippet of the response.     ` {
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 9,
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 850,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "metricbeat-6.6.1-2019.04.16",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "0-NKJWoBbZBDQ7HS6_Jn",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : { }
      }
    ]
  }
} `

Comment: Try running with below query  {"query":{"bool":{"must": [{"range": {"system.cpu.cores": {"boost": 1}}},{"range": {"@timestamp": {"gte": "now-10m","lte": "now/m"}}}]}}}

Comment: Still not working. I am getting response from elasticsearch but "norm" value i still not into response.

Comment: I have edited the question and have added my metricbeat.reference.yml file config settings. Let me know if this correct.

Comment: metricbeat.reference.yml  is only reference file.  you should be updating modules.d/system.yml